# Python error, 1064 on sql statement using mysqldb module

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x

I have developed code using python MySQLdb to connect to mysql database and execute several commands/queries.

I am successfully able to execute all other commands except \s.
Whereas, while executing the same command on Mysql shell works fine.

Sample code:

```
conn = MySQLdb.connect(host=host,user=user,passwd=passwd,unix_socket=unix_socket)
cursor = conn.cursor()
cmd = r"\s"
cursor.execute(cmd)
data = cursor.fetchall()
```

Receiving below error while executing:

**1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '\s' at line 1"**

Comment: What do you expect that `\s` will do as SQL statement? If you want to execute shell command - look at `subprocess` module

Comment: \s will Show the current MySQL Shell status

Comment: yes, as a shell command, not SQL statement